# SQL Server 2008 : SELECT two fields from db, append text, and UPDATE column with results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-update

I have a web application that is syncing to LDAP/eDirectory and it's data is stored in a SQL Server 2008 Enterprise database.

Our organization has just migrated to MS/AD, and with this migration came a new user account naming convention, which of course changed everyone's email address.

The web application uses the `EMAIL` field in the `CLIENT` table of the database as a primary/required field, so, if I can modify the existing `CLIENT.EMAIL` recordset to reflect the new email address format, and sync to AD, all of the remaining account info will be updated without losing any accounts and without those accounts losing access to their history within the web application (I've tested this by modifying a single `EMAIL` record and syncing to AD, then that account could login with AD credentials and see all account history that was created with the LDAP/eDir user account).

I could do this manually (updated 1,255 records), but I thought a SQL query would be a better solution.

What I have done so far is write the following `SELECT` statement (which has provided me with the result that I want to insert into the production database's EMAIL column):

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME + '.' + LAST_NAME + '@email.com' FROM db_name.TABLE_NAME
```

What I need to be able to do with this result is `UPDATE` the `EMAIL` field/column (which currently has a `LAST_NAMEFIRST_INITIAL@email.com` format) with the result of the above `SELECT` statement.

If I add an: `UPDATE CLIENT.EMAIL` line above this statement, I get a syntax error on the SELECT portion shown above.

I want to:

- take the existing `EMAIL` field (which shows `smithj@email.com` for client John Smith),
- then `SELECT` the first and last name fields separated by a '.' and append `@email.com` to the end so that I end up with `john.smith@email.com` for that same record (and UPDATE the entire EMAIL field/column with the appropriate entry based on a FIRST_NAME.LAST_NAME@email.com format.

Is this possible? If so, how do I get around the syntax errors I keep getting? Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I'm guessing you're lucky that no two people share the same name in your organisation?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE db_name.TABLE_NAME
SET EMAIL = FIRST_NAME + '.' + LAST_NAME + '@email.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two separate tables and without knowing the ID linking but this should help

```
UPDATE Client SET email =
    (SELECT FIRST_NAME + '.' + LAST_NAME + '@email.com' 
     FROM db_name.TABLE_NAME AS ldap WHERE ldap.ADGuid = Client.ADGuid)
```

If it's only one table then all you need is

```
UPDATE Client SET email = SELECT FIRST_NAME + '.' + LAST_NAME + '@email.com'
```

Comment: tks!   Received the following response:  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'ADGuid'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'ADGuid'.

Comment: You could probably replace ADGuid with whatever column uniquely identifies your user. Seph had to guess because you didn't include that detail - instead you mixed us up using CLIENT in one sentence and then TABLE_NAME in another.

Answer (score 0):

Join the directory table to the client table and do the update like so:

```
UPDATE c 
SET c.EMAIL = d.FIRST_NAME + '.' + d.LAST_NAME 
FROM CLIENT c 
INNER JOIN DIRECTORY d ON (whatever you need to do to join them goes here.  you can join using multiple criteria with substrings, for instance)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

First, check if this shows what you want:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME
     , LAST_NAME
     , email AS currentEmail
     , FIRST_NAME + '.' + LAST_NAME
       + SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('@', email), LEN(email)) 
       AS EmailToBeWritten
FROM Client ;
```

Then, if you are absolutely sure that the `EmailToBeWritten` is showing exactly what you want to update the `email` field with, use:

```
UPDATE Client 
  SET email = FIRST_NAME + '.' + LAST_NAME
              + SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('@', email), LEN(email)) ;
```